# Обернуть свои UI тесты в docker(pytest,allure,selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, docker

друзья! Являюсь новичком по докеру, умею только останавливать, запускать контейнеры, делать простенький докерфайл.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как свои тесты и браузер хром, добавить в образ докера и их запускать?
Структура тестов:

```
--/pages/ shop_page.py

conftest.py
pytest.ini
test_shop_page.py
```

Запускаю на локальной машине так: pytest -v

Comment: Тут задействовано три компонента: 1. тесты 2. приложение, которое тестируем 3. браузер. Что из этого вы хотите запускать в докере?

Comment: Приветствую! Пока для обучения на своей впс делаю, думаю что тесты и браузер.  Приложение которое тестируем, будет задаваться в driver.get("url") самого теста

Comment: То где приложение - важно, т.к. нужно обеспечить доступ к нему из контейнера с браузером, в зависимости от того, где приложение запущено, это делается по разному.

Comment: Приложение будет внешнее, я так понял проект с селениумом сложнее в докер сунуть, у меня есть небольшое апи на fastapi, думал по аналогии сделать как с селениумом

Comment: Ничего сложного в запуске в докер нет. Нужно только задачу сформулировать, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде - вопрос плохо сформулирован, и подлежит закрытию.

Comment: Исправил вопрос